# Finding the linear recurrence (of a recursive algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I need help with finding the complexity of a recursive algorith; I know that in order to solve this I have to find the linear recurrence, then apply the Master Theorem. As of my knowledge, finding the recurrence would be straightforward when only one parameter is considered;
In this case there are two parameters (i, j). Consider the function below called on (A,1,n):

```
   integer stuff(integer [] A, integer i, integer j){
           if i ≥ j then return i – j 
           integer h ← 0
           for integer k ← 1 to floor((j – i + 1)/3) do {
              h ← h + 1
           }
           return stuff(A, i , i + h) + stuff(A, j – h, j) – stuff(A, i + h + 1, j – h − 1)
   }
```

Assuming various things, I guessed the relation to be:

```
T(1) = k  
T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/3) + T(n/3) + 1/3*n = 3*T(n/3) + 1/3*n
```

I assumed that because it looks that the function is called over 3 parts of 3, of which each is one third of n; being h = O(n/3)

```
First call: h+i-i = h ~ n/3   
Second call: j-(j-h) = h ~ n/3   
Third call: j-h-1-(i+h) = j-i-2h ~ n/3 (which I only assumed)
```

Even though I can try to guess the relation and make sense out of it, I don't know how to *formally* prove it.
If my guessing is correct, how do you get to that conclusion? If not, what am I missing?

Sorry for the long question, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you `return` inside the `for`, it means all the time the function will be finished just with a constant complexity! Because all the time goes to the `for` loop and it `return` the value of the function and everything is finished and the result is ready to be returned.

Also, the proof of the recurrent relationship comes from your analysis. If you use some counting principle in Combinatorics, the final result will be proved.

Moreover, if you correct the pseudocode and put the `return` at the end of the function, the complexity is `T(n) = 3T(n/3) + \Theta(n)` (as you analyzed). Now, from the master theorem, you can say that `T(n) = n log(n))`.

Comment: thanks for pointing me the error in where I wrote the return. I am quite new to the subject, and I still don't understand exactly how and why we can approximate something like `j-i-2h` (in this particular case) to n/3 through the entire loop. I mean, why can we assume the variable `i` as constant and ignore it?

Comment: And to generalize, does this sort of method of considering the interval between the parameters work everytime with a funcion with k parameters dependent on n? Or does it depend on what the function does with thoes parameters (because in the case of `stuff(A,i,j)` the complexity of the loop depends on the diference between the two parameters)? Anyway, thanks for answering

Comment: @ungukla indeed constant values here does not change the asymptotic complexity. Also, just the first level is important in the writing of the recurrent relation. As in the first level `j` is `n` and `i` is `1` just you can ignore `i` there.